# Which test result do I go with when testing for normality, Shapiro-Wilks or Anderson-Darling?

Tags: normality-assumption

Using the Shapiro Wilks test my data proved normally distributed, the Anderson darling test proved the same data was not normal, which test result do I go with when testing for normality? (My sample size is 40).

Comment: Neither test "proved" anything.  You are better off plotting your data so you can understand *how* they are distributed and then relate that to what you ultimately want to do with your data (testing Normality almost never is the final objective of data analysis).  Use a Normal QQ plot.

Comment: [some answers here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/90697/is-shapiro-wilk-the-best-normality-test-why-might-it-be-better-than-other-tests?rq=1)